# Отсутствует перевод "Other action"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Отсутствует перевод.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перевод добавлен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил свой вариант:

You have taken one or more actions on this question and have finished your review. - [Вы выполнили одно или несколько действий с этим вопросом и завершили проверку.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16899)

Other action - [Другие действия](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16897)

Comment: У нас review обычно переводится как "проверка".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight пофиксил